# Samba not forcing permissions (copy/move)

Tags: samba

I've forced 1775 permissions on directories with `force directory mode = 1775`. It works when I create a new directory however it's not working when I copy/move files. Is there any other option for this?

Regards

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you expect and what you get? What Samba version are you using?

Comment: SambaBox: CentOS 6.3, samba-3.5.10-125.el6.x86_64. I'm accessing Samba server from my notebook (CIFS mount). I've set `force directory mode = 1775` and when I create a directory from my notebook the permissions are as expected `drwxrwsr-t` (I also explicitly set GUID) however when I copy or move a directory from my notebook to a Samba share the permissions are `drwxrwxr-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force directory mode` directive only influences the creation of the directory -- it doesn't have any affect if the client then sets the mode on an existing directory. You'll probably find that the copy process first creates the directory, and then sets the mode to match the source. Try to do the copy with something which does not preserve the mode (e.g. `cp` without `--preserve`, `-p` or `-a`).

Comment: I've tested and it actually works correctly from the command line. It also works fine from Windows machine - so this is related to Nautilus (Ubuntu 12.04)?